# Tensorboard did't open in my Anaconda Prompt

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

[image]
I heard pytorch also can use tensorboard.
after installing tensorboard I tried to open tensorboard in my Anaconda Prompt.
I found this,  but I don't know how to solve this problem. and what is this problem

```
File "D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\program.py", line 507, in server_bind
super(WerkzeugServer, self).server_bind()
File "D:\anaconda\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in server_bind
self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
File "D:\anaconda\lib\socket.py", line 676, in getfqdn
hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: invalid start byte
```